# Troubleshooting Missing Data Sample Packets in xBee?

Tags: xbee

I have my first two nodes setup, I have a ZigBee Coordinator API module and a ZigBee End Device API module. I have the end point connected on Analog pins 1-3 with sensors for temp, moisture, and light.

I have the pins D1-3 configured for ADC, and the IR sample rate setting at EA60 for once per 60 seconds.

The frames log on the co-ordinator shows a stream of Explicit RX Indicator frames and Transmit Status frames, but I am seeing no IO Data Sample RX Indicator frames.

Also, I wired an LED to the sleep indicator pin, and it is almost constantly lit, it's certainly not sleeping for a minute at a time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do the Explicit RX Indicator frames look like they might contain your I/O samples?  You might need to set `ATAO=0` to receive the `0x92` frame type, but you're probably better off sticking with parsing the Explicit Rx to find the I/O sample payload and using that.

Regarding your sleeping end device, have you configured the various XBee registers to have it sleep?  Find the section on sleep in your XBee documentation and read through it entirely -- there are many configuration options.  For the ZigBee specification, you'll need to wake up every 7 seconds, even if it's just a short wakeup for the device to ping its parent device and check for network messages.

Finally, make sure you've wired your LED correctly.  If the sleep indicator pin is active low, it will be pulled low whenever sleeping.  And the end device will be waking for a short amount of time, possibly too short to see on an LED.  You could use a scope or a logic analyzer to monitor the pin for changes instead.

Comment: I rebuilt some things and got data, so while I don't know exactly what I did, the payloads did eventually come through, thanks!